# joomla sef redirect component view to default view

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, sef

there are 5 views in my component all was worked fine both with sef on/off.

but recently when i add pagination to 3 views then after make sef on they redirect to component home page but rest of the 2 works fine.

i have tested all of the things as per my knowledge but didnot get the actual point,
please anyone help me out of this.

Ps-> I have not used router.php in my component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,i got an answer after lots of debugging.

there is an component joom sef which saved urls and redirect to there respected sef url.

we need to disable or delete these urls from joom sef and thats all.